# Как лучше сверстать многоугольник с изображением внутри?

Tags: html, css

[image: многоугольник]

Как лучше сверстать многоугольник подобного плана с изображением внутри? Изначально изображение квадратное.

Comment: картинку вырежьте и вставьте!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вот рабочий вариант:

```css
.polygon {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 220px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.cover {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 220px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
.count {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: red;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  z-index: 3;
}
.image {
  position: absolute;
  width: 104%;
  height: 104%;
  left: -2%;
  top: -1%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="polygon">
<svg id="cover" class="cover" data-name="cover" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 131.9276 145.1102"><title>Cover</title><path d="M693.8333,429.1667" transform="translate(-641.3447 -348.1563)" fill="none" stroke="#575756" stroke-miterlimit="10"/><path d="M641.3484,348.1563v145.11H773.2624v-145.11H641.3484Zm128.8036,97.1444A20.4407,20.4407,0,0,1,759.96,462.9952L717.568,487.5267a20.3438,20.3438,0,0,1-20.3886-.0023l-11.057-6.4017-29.7575,8.6113a6.8684,6.8684,0,0,1-5.0909-.4223,4.5167,4.5167,0,0,1-2.5566-5.1227l3.8246-22.6976-0.0033-.0084a20.45,20.45,0,0,1-7.9394-16.1826V396.2376a20.4407,20.4407,0,0,1,10.1924-17.6946l42.3917-24.5315a20.3441,20.3441,0,0,1,20.3847,0L759.96,378.543a20.4408,20.4408,0,0,1,10.1924,17.6946v49.063Z" transform="translate(-641.3447 -348.1563)" fill="#fff"/><path d="M760.0494,378.4665l-42.5182-24.5479a20.4456,20.4456,0,0,0-20.4456,0l-42.5182,24.5479a20.4456,20.4456,0,0,0-10.2228,17.7064v49.0958a20.4471,20.4471,0,0,0,7.9631,16.1934l0.0033,0.0084-3.836,22.7127a4.5174,4.5174,0,0,0,2.5643,5.1261,6.9034,6.9034,0,0,0,5.1061.4225l29.8464-8.617,11.09,6.4059a20.4455,20.4455,0,0,0,20.4494.0022l42.5182-24.5479a20.4455,20.4455,0,0,0,10.2228-17.7064V396.1729A20.4456,20.4456,0,0,0,760.0494,378.4665Z" transform="translate(-641.3447 -348.1563)" fill="none" stroke="#575756" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="6"/></svg>
  <div class="count">22</div>
  <div class="image" style="background-image:url(http://sugilitesalon.com/images/slider/image2.jpg)"></div>
</div>
```

Я специально не вставлял SVG файлом, чтоб вы могли подобрать нужные цвета, думаю, что с этим проблем не возникнет. Если не хочется долбать браузеры отрисовкой svg объектов, можно сделать обычный [png-файл](http://agstudio.pro/images/cover.png) и наложить его по тому же принципу.

Comment: Всем спасибо кто откликнулся, буду иметь ввиду все варианты. Алексей, тебе отдельное спасибо, хороший вариант, им и воспользовался, самому в голову что-то не пришел. Ещё раз всем спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Могу предложить такой сайт:
[Polygon Drawing](http://betravis.github.io/shape-tools/polygon-drawing/)

```css
div {
  background: url("http://www.sukraglobal.com/images/export/wisky.jpg");
  outline: 2px solid red;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  clip-path: polygon(66.67px 200.00px, 197.33px 172.47px, 225.67px 300.47px, 333.33px 200.00px, 266.67px 84.53px, 133.33px 84.53px);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: только надо напомнить о поддержке http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path  особенно, как всегда Edge :'-(

Comment: @АлексейШиманский  не без этого...))

Comment: @C.Raf.T Добавьте, пожалуйста, информацию о браузерной поддержке в ответ, желательно в начало.

Answer (score 2):

Это конечно не то что у вас в примере но если к примеру путь взять из Inkscape т.е заменить **poligon-points** то в полне можно добиться вашего результата

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="200" height="200">
      <image xlink:href="http://img2.vetton.ru/upl/5000/4733/vetton_ru_wallpapers5-1920x1080.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="350" height="200" />
    </pattern>
  </defs>

  <polygon points="20 60, 45 72, 80 10, 130 150, 72 160, 0 85, 10 15" style="fill:url(#img1); stroke:red; stroke-width: 6;" />

</svg>
```

[Вот](http://cssplant.com/clip-path-generator) кстати не хилый генератор для этих случаев и **100%** кроссбраузерно , я о `SVG`

Это пример на кодепен из генератора : http://codepen.io/Geyan/pen/YNKMgK?editors=110
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]